# Cannot set custom SEI using Media Foundation h264 encoder

Tags: video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I have set up a `MFSinkWriter` that takes a RGB `MFMediaType` in input and generates a H.264 `MFMediaType` as output.
I need to add SEI information for every `MFSample` that is encoded. using Windows Media Foundation it should be possible to do so using the attribute `MF_MT_FORWARD_CUSTOM_SEI` for the output `MFMediaType`.

When encoding, before passing the `MFSample` to the `MFSinkWriter`, I add the `MFSampleExtension_Encryption_SEIData` with a blob containing the custom info that I need. However, when inspecting the produced file the SEI field are empty.
There is no documentation/sample on how to use `MF_MT_FORWARD_CUSTOM_SEI` or `MFSampleExtension_Encryption_SEIData`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> ... using Windows Media Foundation **it should be possible to do so** using the attribute `MF_MT_FORWARD_CUSTOM_SEI`...

> ... There is no documentation/sample on how to use `MF_MT_FORWARD_CUSTOM_SEI` or MFSampleExtension_Encryption_SEIData

No, this is impossible. Specifically because there is no documented behavior for this, and there is no undocumented behavior for this too. You can achieve the desired by not using Sink Writer: if you manage the encoder yourself and you have raw H.264 output then you can update the NAL units and amend them with additional SEI NAL units you need.